# Print json in pretty format using php code

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have array like below.

```
 $resultArr = array();     
 $resultArr['status code'] = 200;
 $resultArr['result'] = "Success";

 $json = json_encode($resultArr,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
 return $json;
```

This is giving result like below

```
  "{\n    \"status code\": \"200\",\n    \"result\": \"Success\",\n}"
```

without Pretty_print the result is like below

```
  "{\"status code\":\"200\",\"result\":\"Success\"}"
```

I want response to be like this

{
     "status code": 200,
     "result": "Success"
    }

Is something like this can be done pls, I am using PHP, Running the request in postman and the response are mentioned above

**Note:** I need to avoid using echo, because we are using code sniffers in project, so echo is not recommended.

Comment: Did you try without the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`?

Comment: this will also give you the same result as you need, i think your string contains some extra chars like that

Comment: What's the exact problem with that? I cannot reproduce your output, see http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/de8a7778ad4edb02852d68a2351a4916893ec68c

Comment: remove echo and use return, i can't use echo, i need to avoid for cod sniffer

Comment: can you check your array contains any whitespace or anything like that by print it alone?

Comment: The result you get without JSON_PRETTY_PRINT is already in the format you want. What you are seeing is just the json as string with escaped characters.

Comment: Where you are getting that data, in XHR? js file? where?

Comment: @jafarpinjar It works as you specify without JSON_PRETTY_PRINT ... when i run this on my box, php 7.2.  Why dont you show your real code ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg, Iam using postman, response is like that

Comment: Postman? Switch tabs to see relevant output you want to, what's the problem?

Comment: @quickSwap, tab is set to json, in postman

Comment: What's exactly problem with that data is my concern, where you want to use that data, android, iphone, php where? What's the later application of data?

Comment: @quickSwap, we are sending response to navision, there its not treating as json instead going as string, that is my concern, use above code as it is i posted, and check how you get the response, then pls try to answer if u can

Comment: Set headers as json and try sending back to that api I guess as response

Answer (score 6):

You used `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` for beautify output purpose,

```
$json = json_encode($resultArr,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

If you want to use it as response remove that parameter,

```
$json = json_encode($resultArr);
```

Above line should work.

Comment: without pretty_print, the result is like below,
"{\"status code\":\"200\",\"result\":\"Success\"}"

Answer (score 2):

First of all, remove the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` flag.

Secondly, your problem is with the backslashes (`\`). These are escape characters. I don't know how you are printing your json or how you are viewing it.

If I do:

```
echo $json;
```

It outputs:

```
{"status code":200,"result":"Success"}
```

The backslashes are probably added because you're doing an AJAX request. In order to solve this, you could use jQueries `.parseJSON()` or add `dataType: "json"` to your ajax request.

And if you really don't want the backslashes to be added:

```
$json = json_encode($resultArr, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

#### Update

It might help to output using the following header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: hi @Peter, $json = json_encode($resultArr, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
this code returns like this, "{\"status code\":\"200\",\"result\":\"Success\"}"

Comment: How/where are yu outputting your JSON?

Comment: Postman probably adds the `\` becuase it is escaping the json. If you start using this response, it will work.

Comment: we are sending the response to navision, so there its treating as string not json

Answer (score 0):

**1. for Output Of API You Can Use Api:**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

**2. Using JSON_PRETTY_PRINT**

```
$json = json_encode($resultArr,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

**3. You want To Display In Chrome**

```
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/json-handle/?src=recommended
```